# Вопрос по state React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, state

У меня есть поле ввода в которое я ввожу название города и после этого получаю координаты города и прогноз погоды. Для этого я создал функциональную компоненту `Content` в которой с помощью библиотеки `axios` получаю ответы от сервера. Изначально у меня установлено 2 состояния компонента:

```
    const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([{
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0
    }]);
    
    const [forecast, setForecast] = useState([{
        dt: 0,
        day: 0,
        max: 0,
        min: 0,
        eve: 0,
        morning: 0,
        night: 0,
        main: '',
        description: '',
        icon: '',
        sunrise: 0,
        sunset: 0
    }]);
```

После того, как я получаю из поля ввода название города я отправляю `GET` запрос по ссылке:

> [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${YOUR_CITY_NAME}&key=${YOUR_TOKEN}](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$%7BYOUR_CITY_NAME%7D&key=$%7BYOUR_TOKEN%7D)

И получаю координаты города: `lat` и `lng` соответственно. И дальше я пытаюсь запихнуть их в стейт `coordinates`.
После этого делаю запрос, но уже на сервер Open Weather Map:

> https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecalllat=${coordinates.lat}&lon=${coordinates.lng}&exclude=hourly,minutely&appid=${YOUR_TOKEN}

Проблема в том, что при первом запросе у меня в `coordinates.lat` и `coordinates.lng` дефолтное значени, т.е 0. Почему-то новый стейт присваивается только после второго нажатия на кнопку вызова функции. И, если, я например введу в инпут "Киев", то получу погоду по координатам lat = 0, lng = 0 и после этого введу в инпут "Москва", то получу погоду по координатам киева, т.е прошлый стейт. Как это исправить? Вот весь код:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Forecast from './Forecast';
import '../style/Content.css';

const axios = require('axios').default;
const moment = require('moment');

const Content = () => {
    const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([{
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0
    }]);
    
    const [forecast, setForecast] = useState([{
        dt: 0,
        day: 0,
        max: 0,
        min: 0,
        eve: 0,
        morning: 0,
        night: 0,
        main: '',
        description: '',
        icon: '',
        sunrise: 0,
        sunset: 0
    }]);

    let inputValue = React.createRef();

    const getCityName = () => inputValue.current.value;

    const getForecastData = async () => {
        axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${getCityName()}&key=${YOUR_TOKEN}`)
            .then(async (res) => {
                const newCoordinates = {
                    lat: await res.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
                    lng: await res.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng
                }
                console.log(newCoordinates.lat, newCoordinates.lng);
                setCoordinates(newCoordinates);
                console.log(coordinates);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
            });

        setTimeout(() => {
            axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${coordinates.lat}&lon=${coordinates.lng}&exclude=hourly,minutely&appid=${YOUR_TOKEN}`)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    const newWeather = {
                        day:         Math.floor(res.data.daily[0].temp.day - 273),
                        max:         Math.floor(res.data.daily[0].temp.max - 273),
                        min:         Math.floor(res.data.daily[0].temp.min - 273),
                        eve:         Math.floor(res.data.daily[0].temp.eve - 273),
                        morning:     Math.floor(res.data.daily[0].temp.morn - 273),
                        night:       Math.floor(res.data.daily[0].temp.night - 273),
                        main:        res.data.daily[0].weather[0].main,
                        description: res.data.daily[0].weather[0].description,
                        icon:        res.data.daily[0].weather[0].icon,
                        dt:          moment(res.data.daily[0].dt, 'X').format('dddd, DD MMM'),
                        sunrise:     moment(res.data.daily[0].sunrise, 'X').format('dddd, HH:mm'),
                        sunset:      moment(res.data.daily[0].sunset, 'X').format('dddd, HH:mm')
                    }

                    setForecast(newWeather);
                    console.log(forecast);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error(err);
                })
        }, 500);
    }

    return (
        <div className='content'>
            <div>
                <input type='text' ref={inputValue} placeholder='City name'></input>
                <button className="btn" onClick={getForecastData}>Go</button>
            </div>
            <Forecast />
        </div>
    );
}

export default Content;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте разберем, что делает ваш код:

1. Вы объявили стейты.
2. Получаем доступ к INPUT в рендере через REF
3. Пытаетесь получить значение INPUT
4. Создали функцию с получением данных.

А теперь какие ошибки увидел я:

1. В стейт вы кладете массив в котором лежит один объект с координатами. Я бы убрал массивы, у вас поиск по одному объекту. А так же не понимаю для чего вам стейт для координат, после изменения стейта произойдет новый рендер, но сам компонент остался без изменений.

```js
    
const [forecast, setForecast] = useState({
  dt: 0,
  day: 0,
  max: 0,
  min: 0,
  eve: 0,
  morning: 0,
  night: 0,
  main: '',
  description: '',
  icon: '',
  sunrise: 0,
  sunset: 0
});
```

2. Вы сразу хотите получить значение из Input, но зачем? компонент только появился, а вы из него уже считываете значение которое будет пустое.
3. При получение данных вы используете setTimeout в 500мс, я так понимаю вы делаете задержку между получением первых данных и вторых. Но если первый запрос будет дольше 500мс, то второй запрос отработает с ошибкой. Почитайте про async/await Promise подробнее.

```js
const getForecastData = async() => {

  try {

    const getCityName = () => inputValue.current.value;

    let getCoordinates = await axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${getCityName()}&key=${YOUR_TOKEN}`).then(res => res.data.results[0].geometry.location);

    const newCoordinates = {
      lat: getCoordinates.lat,
      lng: getCoordinates.lng
    }

    let getForecast = await axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${coordinates.lat}&lon=${coordinates.lng}&exclude=hourly,minutely&appid=${YOUR_TOKEN}`).then(res => res.data.daily[0]);

    const newWeather = {
      day: Math.floor(getForecast.temp.day - 273),
      max: Math.floor(getForecast.temp.max - 273),
      min: Math.floor(getForecast.temp.min - 273),
      eve: Math.floor(getForecast.temp.eve - 273),
      morning: Math.floor(getForecast.temp.morn - 273),
      night: Math.floor(getForecast.temp.night - 273),
      main: getForecast.weather[0].main,
      description: getForecast.weather[0].description,
      icon: getForecast.weather[0].icon,
      dt: moment(getForecast.dt, 'X').format('dddd, DD MMM'),
      sunrise: moment(getForecast.sunrise, 'X').format('dddd, HH:mm'),
      sunset: moment(getForecast.sunset, 'X').format('dddd, HH:mm')
    }

    setForecast(newWeather);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

}
```